# Order of recreation and proposing of block

Tags: go-ethereum, quorum, ibft

With regard to [this](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/21359) post, I would like to know what happens if the proposing and recreation of a block happens at the same time. For instance, if we keep the default recommit interval of 3s and set the block period to 6s. Is the order of the two events fixed at time 6 or is it random because the two events are completely independent of each other?

If the block is proposed before the block is "recreated", transactions that arrived between times 3 and 6 will not be included in the block. If the recration occurs before the block is proposed, the transactions will be included.

Comment: Block time in a pow blockchain is random, so it is unlikely it will be 6 seconds. In any case there are synchronization primitives protecting the data so if both coincide at the same time only one of them will have priority, sometimes a new block with fresh transactions will be created or some transactions will have to wait an extra block period.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i should have mentioned that my question apllies to [IBFT](https://docs.goquorum.consensys.net/en/stable/Concepts/Consensus/IBFT/) where blocktime and recommit interval can be set via flags. The answer helps me anyway.